# How to change url's in Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have created a website and my client want that the URLs shows in tab according like Login URL is `www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=login` and he want that there will be set in url `www.domain.com/login` instead of this. So please tell me how can I do this I am new in Joomla

Answer (score 1):

Check This:

http://www.teachmejoomla.net/joomla-mambo-tutorials-and-howtos/general-questions/how-to-enable-seo-on-joomla.html

On `SEO URL's` , `apache mod_re-write` from you `Global Configuration` option.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check yes to apache mod_rewrite, enable SEO, in global configuration, but also a very important part... in your root folder for Joomla you need to rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess  - that's VERY important!

That should help you get what you want.  I recommend doing some reading up on the documentation - it's all covered in there!

Comment: Thanks for your answer i got it successfully

Comment: If this answer helped you - please make sure you check this as the answer so that others know they can find the answer here.