# how to modify an article url in joomla 2.5.6 to a simpler url

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I have an article link and i want this link to be shortened and meaningful so how can i achieve this in joomla 2.5.6.

here is the actual url:

```
 www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=11
```

and i would like to have this like

```
 www.example.com/some-link
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633001/how-to-change-urls-in-joomla/7633051#7633051

Comment: it helped and now i am left with this link www.example.com/parent/child  and i need to have link like this www.example.com/child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install joomsef component and customize your component as you want.
Joomsef is a free joomla component and it is very helpfull.